# Capitalize first letter in the list

Tags: python, capitalize

List_1 = ['KEYUR', 'MoNica', 'tom', 'MuRali'], I want first letter of each word in Caps and rest in lower case and the output should be in a single line.

I have tried the below code, but the output I receive is vertical.

```
input_list=['VARMA', 'raj', 'Gupta', 'SaNdeeP']
for line in input_list:
    L1 = line.title()
    print(L1)
```

What changes are required to get the desired output ?

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [item.capitalize() for item in List_1]
```

Answer (score 1):

something like the below

```
lst = ['KEYUR', 'MoNica', 'tom', 'MuRali']
lst = [x[0].upper() + x[1:].lower() for x in lst]
print(' '.join(lst))
```

output

```
Keyur Monica Tom Murali
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) method.

> Return a titlecased version of the string where words start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are lowercase.

```py
>>> input_list=['VARMA', 'raj', 'Gupta', 'SaNdeeP']
>>> input_list = [i.title() for i in input_list]
>>> input_list
['Varma', 'Raj', 'Gupta', 'Sandeep']
```